# How to mark multiple lines as NON-NLS

Tags: eclipse

I'm developing an Eclipse plug-in with lots of string constants which i do not want to externalize/translate.

In the current situation, i have to mark each string with a NON-NLS comment:

```java
private String STRING_A = "string a"; //$NON-NLS-1$
private String STRING_B = "string b"; //$NON-NLS-1$
private String STRING_C = "string c"; //$NON-NLS-1$
```

This isn't a big problem for a few lines like in the example, but i'm going to need hundreds of these lines.

I do not want to use `@SuppressWarnings("nls")`, because the "externalize strings"-wizard kindly ignores the SuppressWarnings annotation and i also have lots of other strings which i do want to externalize.

Is something like this possible?

```java
// $NON-NLS-START$
private String STRING_A = "string a";
private String STRING_B = "string b";
private String STRING_C = "string c";
// $NON-NLS-END$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible at the moment. However, NON-NLS areas would be a nice thing to request via https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=PDE&component=UI, additionally to the fact that the `Externalize Strings` wizard should offer option to honor the `@SuppressWarnings("nls")`

Comment: Did not get a meaningful reply yet on the eclipse board, but for future reference: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=500809

Comment: Such a feature is still not planned for Eclipse, but i could move the strings i do not want to externalize to a new class and add the `@SuppressWarnings("nls")` there. That way new strings in my current class will still be found by the `Externalize Strings` wizard, which is good enough for now.